# iPhone - UITableView to show two different custom cell views

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my `UITableView`, I want to show loading indicator in the last cell.
For remaining cells, I created a custom table view cell which is working fine. But when I scroll to the end, its crashing and not able to load loading indictor (which is a different custom cell view). Here's my code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HomeViewCell";

    UITableViewCell* cellToReturn = nil;

    // Configure the cell.
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    if (row < [jokesTableArray count])
    {
        CustomTableCell* cell = (CustomTableCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[CustomTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
        NSDictionary* dict = [jokesTableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSNumber* rating = [[ServerCommunicator getInstance] getCurrentUserJokeRating:[dict objectForKey:@"id"]];
        cell.userRatedTheJoke = rating != nil ? YES : NO;
        cell.titleLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"text"]; 
        cell.upVotes.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.2f",[[dict objectForKey:@"rating_count"] floatValue]];
        [cell setRating:rating != nil ? [rating intValue] : [[dict objectForKey:@"rating_count"] intValue]];
        NSString* authorName = [dict objectForKey:@"author"];
        if (authorName != nil && ![authorName isEqual:[NSNull null]]) 
        {
            cell.author.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"By:%@",authorName];     
        }
        cellToReturn = cell;
    } 
    else 
    {
        KMLoadingIndicatorCell* cell = (KMLoadingIndicatorCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            KMLoadingIndicatorCell* cell = [[[KMLoadingIndicatorCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
            cell.loadingLabel.text = @"Loading...";
            cellToReturn = cell;
        }
    }

    return cellToReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a different Cell Identifier for your custom cell.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the same `reuseIdentifier`, the line

```
KMLoadingIndicatorCell* cell = (KMLoadingIndicatorCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

is most likely setting `cell` to an instance of `CustomTableCell` that is now being reused, rather than the expected `KMLoadingIndicatorCell`. You should be using different identifiers for the two different types of cells.