# TableView with different cell types or ScrollView with inner TableViews

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I saw many stackoverflow questions, but I could not come to a definite answer.

I need to create the following screen (detailview):

[image]

It's wide ScrollView screen which contains among other custom UITableViewCells of different types. 
NewsCell and SongCell - are two custom UITableViewCells classes, which appear differently.

How to properly implement such a screen?

Option 1:
Use UITableViewController and UITableVIewCells of different types:PhotoCell, DescriptionCell, NewsCell, SomeTextCell, SongCell.

Option 2:
Use UIScrollViewController, which contains other elements (Image, Labels, UTableView for news and UITableView for songs. (But I read that insert UITableView into UIScrollView it's wrong, because UITableView is subclass of UIScrollView)

Option 3:
Something else.

Waiting for your comments!

Comment: You can use different type if identifier for this. BAsed on identifier you can choose its style.

Comment: This also using some option to solve similar problem like you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575533/iphone-uitableview-to-show-two-different-custom-cell-views

Comment: Option 1 is best way to perform...

Comment: option 1 will be awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create multiple custom cells and start integrate into your tableview. If you want to show the cells based upon the content you can calculate the internal elements size and take the highest element hight and make the cell height. Now you can observe that cells will display based upon the highest element hight.I think it will full fill your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a pattern like a header followed by few cells, then you can use sections which is a feature in [uitableview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).